# How to find xpath by element text in selenium ide in order to use the element?

Tags: selenium-ide

Table contains columns with headers like those

```
vehicle no | driver

103        |   John
```

the *xpath* location is:

```
//tr[3]/td[4]  |  //tr[3]/td[5]
```

The columns can be customized and then *xpath* will change therefore, is there a way to automatically find the *xpath* location of the columns by contained text ?

For now i'm using loop with scanning all of the headers, maybe there is more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming that your table would look some thing like below..

```
<table>
<th> <td> vehicle no</td> <td> driver</td></th>
<tr> <td> 103</td> <td> John</td></tr>
</table>
```

To create xpath location of the column,  by contained text ? You can use 'contains' in xpath..

```
 XPATH1 =  //table//td[contains(.,'John')]
  XPATH2 =    //table//td[text()='John']
```

Please let me know if the above does not solve your problem.

Comment: How can I use the "contains" option? Is it java script?

Comment: By using 'contains' function in XPath, we can extract all the elements which matches a particular text value.

Comment: Thanks, could you please specify how to use this option in IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for exact search:

```
//td[text()='EXACT']
```

Or for partial search:

```
//td[contains(text(),'PARTIAL')]
```

This gives you two options in xpath to patch for text.

Comment: Thanks, how can I use it in Selenium IDE?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. That's the xpath you use as a locator. If you want to click on it you select click and use the above xpath as the locator

Comment: It works great for me, thanks. Is there a way to locate in element like this? //div[@id='mif-tree-6']/span/span[3]. I tried to use the examples you gave in next way //div[text()='EXACT']/span/span[3] and it does not work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. you can locate using any valid xpath.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this helps?

if you want to get 'John':

in the command field put: [verify text]

in the target field put: xpath=//table//td[contains(.,'driver')]/following::tr/td[2]

in the value field put: John